# Play ".ch" extension stream on HTML

Tags: html, javascript, html5, jplayer

I am trying to play .ch stream from a html player. But can't find the solution.

.ch streams can be played successfully in Android via "[ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer)". But I want to embed them to my website too, but none of html5 players can do as far as I searched.

Please kindly help me to for the solution.

Comment: There is not enough information here to help. Can you provide more specific details?

Answer (score 2):

.ch is nothing more than a ccTLD, which represents the country of Switzerland. From my knowledge and research, there is nothing inherently special about .ch, or any domain extension for that matter when it comes to streaming.

There is, however, a domain extension which is marketed for streaming music and/or video. That extension is none other than: ".stream". Here is what [Godaddy has to say about (dot)stream](https://www.godaddy.com/tlds/stream-domain).

Look it, at the end of the day, domains are domains. Use .ch if you are intending to target users of Switzerland, as that is the purpose of this ccTLD.

If you want to buy a .stream domain name - there is nothing special about it other than the extension which implies your intent to "stream".. if you will.